# Creating Individual PDF Reports - Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, report

I have an interesting requirement. In Access (2010) I need to generate individual PDF reports, in which the unique ID is in the report i.e. **F9902_ReportName.pdf**

The below code successfully can generate individual reports exactly how I want them to work, the only problem is it hits resource limits when running. As a result I get the following error: *Run-time error '3035'. System resource exceeded*. If I understand it right the `DoCmd.OpenReport` & `DoCmd.OutputTo` are both opening reports but only one is being closed in the `DoCmd.Close` command, the other stays hidden and holds resources and once the loop processes about 400 time it hits the resource limit. I have looked through several web pages to solve this issue but every one seems to stop at this specific issue.

The problem is I want to use the `DoCmd.OutputTo` function only but it does not allow me to filter on a per record basis (to my knowledge) which is why I must utilize the `DoCmd.OpenReport` before it.

```
Private Sub Command526_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim temp As String

    mypath = "C:\location\"

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [NameOfTable]", dbOpenDynaset)

    Do While Not rs.EOF

    temp = rs("Ref#")
    MyFileName = temp & "_PdfOutput.pdf"

    DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewReport, , "[Ref#]='" & temp & "'"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "ReportName"

    rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to not filter the report when opening it, but filter its recordsource by using a public function.

In a public module, you have this code:

```
Dim strCurRef as string

Public Function GetCurrentRef() As String
    GetCurrentRef = strCurRef
End Function

Public Sub SetCurrentRef(strRef As String)
    strCurRef = strRef 
End Sub
```

And you create a query as recordsource for the report that filters the data by `GetCurrentRef()`:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE [Ref#] = GetCurrentRef()
```

And before exporting your report to PDF, you set the current data:

```
temp = rs("Ref#")
MyFileName = temp & "_PdfOutput.pdf"
Call SetCurrentRef(temp)

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "ReportName", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
```

Comment: This corrects the resource limit issue, it now outputs the full amount of reports and names them correctly. The issue now is that the reports themselves do not have any data in them, they are simply a blank template. So it seems the issue is that OutputTo is not getting any data...

Comment: Have you included "ReportName" in the `DoCmd.OutputTo` call? If yes, do `DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview` and set a breakpoint afterwards - does it show the selected record?

Comment: Yes. I just executed with `acViewPreview` command, the report displayed as empty.

Comment: Then your query (the report recordsource) doesn't work as it should. Call `SetCurrentRef` with an existing Ref# (e.g. in the Immediate Window), then open the query and edit it until it shows the selected record.

Comment: Your debugging idea worked! It made me realise you wrote in your original code `strRef = GetCurrentRef` in the `SetCurrentRef()` function instead of `strCurRef = GetCurrentRef` as the variable which you declared globally. Running now, will update if it works :)

Comment: Ouch, that's what happens when posting untested code... `SetCurrentRef` was totally off and `GetCurrentRef()` needs the correct variable too, see edit.

Comment: there was a user called Andre;

who helped out struggling rj;

turns out you can use OutputTo;

just SQL filter to source em through;

the reports will output one by one;

then sit an wait until the loop is done;